# Changing Bootstrap Grid When Styling CSS for Print

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a DOM structure on a page which looks something like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-7 col-sm-8">
       Wide Stuff Here
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-5 col-sm-4">
       Narrow Stuff Here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I style this structure for print, I mostly hide  things that are inside the narrower column on the right. However, I still would like to display two things from within it on a printed page. The problem is that there is a lot more content inside the wider container on the left. As a result, when that content gets past the content in the right column, it looks out of place on the page due to empty white space to its right.

My question is how one can address this. I thought of somehow letting content from within the left, wide column to take full width starting from a certain point or container, but am not sure how to achieve that. I am also open to other ideas on how one could present this better.

To be a little more specific, this page displays a cooking recipe. In the left column, there is a large picture of the dish as well as a list of pictures and steps for its preparation. In the right column, there is a box with ingredients and a box with the recipe's rating.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: You could display the divs above each other instead of next to each other. Making the wide column full width only when passing the narrow columns content is not possible in css.

Comment: @TVBZ which divs do you mean?

Comment: The columns (wide stuff & narrow stuff). It wouldn't look like columns next to each other, but more like rows above each other.

Comment: @TVBZ I believe it makes sense to have information about ingredients and picture of the dish to be side by side. Then, the preparation steps follow below, occupying full width of the page.

Comment: I understand. But it won't work with current html structure. You could try to divide your html into multiple rows and balance it out. Or maybe write your own css grid, that would probably be easier to work with.